# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" When i trying to read json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
j = """
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",       
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "id": "IEEhzQoKtQU",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "171938",
        "likeCount": "5856",
        "dislikeCount": "38",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "368"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
"""
    
js = json.loads(j)
    
js = js["items"]
    
js = js["statistics"]
    
print(js["viewCount"])
```

Im new to json and im trying to retrive the viewCount from this json string. But everytime i run the code i get this error:

```
js = js["statistics"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `"items"` is a list. Notice the `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `items` list is indeed a list, not a dictionary. In your json:

```
[
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "id": "IEEhzQoKtQU",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "171938",
        "likeCount": "5856",
        "dislikeCount": "38",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "368"
      }
    }
  ]
```

There's only one item, but you have a list. If you want the *first item in the list*, you would use `js[0]["statistics"]`. Or to iterate over them, `for item in js`.